# how to scrape websites that have loaders?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

i'm trying to scrape the website that contains loading screens. when i browse the website it shows loading.. for a sec and then it loads up. But the problem is when i try to scrape it using `scrapy` it gives me nothing (probably because of that loading). can i solve the problem using `scrapy` or should i use some other tools?
here's the link to the website if you wanna see https://www.graana.com/project/601/lotus-lake-towers

Comment: Maybe the "loading" screen was designed specifically to prevent scraping?

Comment: yes that's the problem :)

Comment: See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/developer-tools.html and https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Network console]As it is sending a GET request to get information about the property , you should mimic the same in your code. (You can observe the GET call under console -> Network -> XHR )

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    import scrapy


    class GranaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
        name = 'grana'
        allowed_domains = 'www.graana.com'
        start_urls = ['https://www.graana.com/api/area/slug/601']

        def parse(self, response):
    #        for url in allurlList:
            scrapy.http.Request(response.url, method='GET' , dont_filter=False)
            print(response.body)
#convert json response to array and save to your storage system
```

Output is in json format, convert it to your convenience.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old and already answered but I wanted to share my solution after encountering a similar problem. The accepted answer was not helpful to me because I was not using scrapy.

I wanted to scrape a website that first displays a loading page and then displays the actual page content.

Here's an example of such a [website](https://www.myjob.mu/ShowResults.aspx?Keywords=&Location=&Category=39&Recruiter=Company&SortBy=MostRecent) :
[image: GIF showing the loading page animation of a website]

The [requests library](https://pypi.org/project/requests/) will not work for such websites. In my experience, `request.get(URL, headers=HEADERS)` simply times out .

## Solution

Use [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/).

- First you need to know approximately how long the loading page animation lasts. In the above website, it takes around 3 seconds.
- The trick is to simply sleep your program for the duration of the animation after navigating to the website with `driver.get(URL)`.
- By the time the program finishes sleeping, the loading animation will be over so we can safely extract the HTML of the actual page content using `driver.page_source`.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time

# the following options are only for setup purposes
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

URL = "https://www.myjob.mu/ShowResults.aspx?Keywords=&Location=&Category=39&Recruiter=Company&SortBy=MostRecent"

driver.get(URL)
time.sleep(5) # any number > 3 should work fine
html = driver.page_source
print(html)
```

[`Beautifulsoup`](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/) library can then be used for parsing the html.

Comment: Thank you very much! This helps me a lot, since it is more generic than the accepted answer.